# Deserializing list objects, properties returning as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, deserialization, frombodyattribute

I'm trying to POST data to an API which should accept a `List<UpdatePointHistory>`. The size of the list is correct but the properties of the objects are blank.

```
public class UpdatePointHistory
{
    string Tree { get; set; }
    string FruitCount { get; set; }
    string Observations { get; set; }
    int PrivateId { get; set; }
}

public void Post([FromBody]List<UpdatePointHistory> updates)
{
    //Do some sort of auth for god sake
    Console.WriteLine("test");
}
```

The data I'm posting:

[image]

And the object returning from the API:

[image]

Comment: All your properties are `private`. They need to be `public` so the model binder knows what to populate

Answer (score 5):

All your properties are `private`. They need to be `public` so the model binder knows what to populate and has access to them.

```
public class UpdatePointHistory
{
    public string Tree { get; set; }
    public string FruitCount { get; set; }
    public string Observations { get; set; }
    public int PrivateId { get; set; }
}
```